# Angular - How to post data to Prestashop webservice

Tags: angular, prestashop-1.7

I am working on an angular application which communicate with the API of Prestashop.

I can easily retrieve the list of products ... because Prestashop can return it in the JSON format.

Now I wish to create data ( POST data ) and Prestashop require XML ... Prestashop provide the blank schema, example :

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <product>
    <id><![CDATA[]]></id>
    <id_manufacturer><![CDATA[]]></id_manufacturer>
    <id_supplier><![CDATA[]]></id_supplier>
    <id_category_default><![CDATA[]]></id_category_default>
    <new><![CDATA[]]></new>
```

Off course I can create the XML with a string but ... is there a better solution to manipulate this type of XML ?
Something like :

- Download the blank XML from http://....
- Set value1 ...
- Post the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full method :

To convert from XML to JSON :

```
var json = JSON.parse(converter.xml2json(xml_as_string, {compact: true, spaces: 4}));
```

To convert from json to XML :

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
var xml = converter.json2xml(jsonString, {compact: true,  spaces: 4});
```

The original data is an XML, consequently the XML header is already available.

ty,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json

To perform the transformation from JSON to XML, you probably need to add a header too:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`